# How can I remove server and path from feed

Tags: sed, feed

I've a feed with products and several images-urls (see below ORIGINAL SOURCE). The urls are with host- path- and filename. But I only want the filename.

So I would like all the URLs changed thus  **http://somewebstore.nl/media/catalog/product/f/i/file.JPG;** must be changed into **file.JPG;** only.

I'm using the following command

**sed -e 's~http://~\n&~g' stap$oldcounter.csv  | sed 's~http://.*/~~' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/;\n/;/#g' > stap$counter.csv**

but this messes up (see below). What I'm I doing wrong or maybe there is a better command for it??

EXAMPLE MESS

```
    Id;Extra;Description;Price;Title;Image1;Image2;Image3;Image4;Image5;Image6;Image7;Image8;Url;PriceOption;Condition;DeliveryOption;Paypal;GroupName
167;;"<p>De Laga Nova Lux is een prachtig voorbeeld van praktisch modern design. <br />Deze revolutionaire haard is een blikvanger in uw tuin en bijzonder handig in het gebruik. <br />Hij is sterk, gemakkelijk verplaatsbaar en dankzij de krachtige schoorsteen, heeft u binnen een handomdraai een heerlijk vuur zonder hinderlijke rook. <br />Tevens leverbaar, schoorsteenverlengbuizen, trekkap en dakdoorvoeren. LET OP de Laga Nova verkleurd na enkele stookbeurten. <br />De Laga Nova Lux wordt geleverd incl bbq rooster, as schepje, pookje, en montage handschoenen en doekje. <br /><br />Maten van de laga Nova lux:&nbsp;<br />Hoogte 188 cm met trekkap 215 cm <br />Hoogte vuurkorf / BBQ 46 cm - Hoogte opening vuurhaard 46 cm <br />Breedte opening 44.5 - Diameter vuurhaard 58 cm <br />Diameter / breedte totaal 74 &nbsp;<br />Pijp hoogte 75 cm <br />Pijp diameter 19.5 <br />Gewicht: 29 kg</p>***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>StoreName</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>StoreName</b><br/>Somestraat 92a<br/>70016 RW SomeCity<br/>0314-432676<br/>";459,95;"Terrashaard Laga Nova Lux. Ruim 9 jaar bewezen product.";
file.JPG;
terrashaarden_verzamel.jpg;
laga_nova_compact_1.jpg;
logo.gif;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
168;;"Exclusieve luxe handvervaardigde terrashaard! Door de juiste keuze van stenen zal deze terrashaard altijd in uw tuin passen.De stenen houden de warmte langer vast. Hierdoor kunt u lang genieten van een aangename temperatuur. Door de schoorsteen heeft u geen last van rook. Afmeting Laga Sten: 80 cm x 60 cm x 220 cm ( incl schoorsteen). Gewicht met steen (gletjer keien) 355 kg.De Laga Sten Tuin haard is voorzien van:- RVS schoorsteen- Gegalvaniseerde afneembare kap- Gegalvaniseerde metalen korf van 4 mm dik staaldraad- Gegalvaniseerd onderstel- Gegalvaniseerd  houtopslag ruimte- gegalvaniseerde aslade- Zwaar brand - kolen rooster- RVS BBQ rooster***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>StoreName</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>StoreName</b><br/>Somestraat 92a<br/>70016 RW SomeCity<br/>0314-432676<br/>";1.099,00;"Terrashaard Laga Sten Gletjer Keien";
file_2.JPG;
logo.gif;;;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
169;;"Tuinhaard Laga StenLaga Sten een mooie tuin/terrashaard die met zijn tijd meegaat.Door de juiste keuze van stenen zal deze terrashaard altijd in uw tuin passen.Het grote voordeel is het rendement van deze kachel. De Laga Sten zorgt als vuurhaard voor een zeer gezellige en comfortabele warmte welke ook de stenen erom heen opwarmt. Deze stenen zorgen op hun beurt  voor een langdurig en behaaglijke warmte welke aanhoud tot lang nadat de Laga sten tuin haard gedooft is.***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>StoreName</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>StoreName</b><br/>Somestraat 92a<br/>70016 RW SomeCity<br/>0314-432676<br/>";1.199,00;"Terrashaard Laga Sten Beach Pebbles";
file_3.JPG;
logo.gif;;;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
170;;"Dit systeem werkt makkelijker dan bij de traditionele gasfles. Een vulbegrenzer zorgt ervoor dat de fles nooit meer dan 80 procent gevuld wordt. Er is een veerbeveiliging die ervoor zorgt dat de druk in de fles niet te hoog wordt. Op de inhoudsmeter is te zien hoeveel gas er nog in de fles is. INCL 3LPG vulnippel's.Fles wordt geleverd met certificaat en TUV keur.Hoogte incl kraag 580 mm (kraag demonteerbaar)Hoogte zonder kraag 555 mmDiameter 300 mmInhoud: 27 ltr (80% 21,6) Leeggewicht: 17,5 kg Let op: Gebruik deze fles enkel rechtopstaand en mag alleen recht opstaand gevuld worden. U mag de fles wel liggend vervoeren (mits de afnamekraan dichtgeschroefd is). Sinds 1-1-2010 is het wettelijk toegestaan deze flessen aan de pomp te vullen. Tevens is het mogelijk de gasfles te vullen met propaan en butaan gas.***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>StoreName</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>StoreName</b><br/>Somestraat 92a<br/>70016 RW SomeCity<br/>0314-432676<br/>";189,95;"Navulbare LPG Gasfles (tank) 27 liter incl koppelverlengstuk en 3 LPG vulnippels.";
file_29.JPG;
logo.gif;;;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
```

ORIGINAL FEED

```
Id;Extra;Description;Price;Title;Image1;Image2;Image3;Image4;Image5;Image6;Image7;Image8;Url;PriceOption;Condition;DeliveryOption;Paypal;GroupName
167;;"<p>De Laga Nova Lux is een prachtig voorbeeld van praktisch modern design. <br />Deze revolutionaire haard is een blikvanger in uw tuin en bijzonder handig in het gebruik. <br />Hij is sterk, gemakkelijk verplaatsbaar en dankzij de krachtige schoorsteen, heeft u binnen een handomdraai een heerlijk vuur zonder hinderlijke rook. <br />Tevens leverbaar, schoorsteenverlengbuizen, trekkap en dakdoorvoeren. LET OP de Laga Nova verkleurd na enkele stookbeurten. <br />De Laga Nova Lux wordt geleverd incl bbq rooster, as schepje, pookje, en montage handschoenen en doekje. <br /><br />Maten van de laga Nova lux:&nbsp;<br />Hoogte 188 cm met trekkap 215 cm <br />Hoogte vuurkorf / BBQ 46 cm - Hoogte opening vuurhaard 46 cm <br />Breedte opening 44.5 - Diameter vuurhaard 58 cm <br />Diameter / breedte totaal 74 &nbsp;<br />Pijp hoogte 75 cm <br />Pijp diameter 19.5 <br />Gewicht: 29 kg</p>***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>HuisEnTuinWinkel</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>HuisEnTuinWinkel</b><br/>Voltastraat 92a<br/>7006 RW Doetinchem<br/>0314-362676<br/>";459,95;"Terrashaard Laga Nova Lux. Ruim 9 jaar bewezen product.";http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/media/catalog/product/f/i/file.JPG;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/media/catalog/product/t/e/terrashaarden_verzamel.jpg;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/media/catalog/product/l/a/laga_nova_compact_1.jpg;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/skin/frontend/default/grayscale2014/images/logo.gif;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
168;;"Exclusieve luxe handvervaardigde terrashaard! Door de juiste keuze van stenen zal deze terrashaard altijd in uw tuin passen.De stenen houden de warmte langer vast. Hierdoor kunt u lang genieten van een aangename temperatuur. Door de schoorsteen heeft u geen last van rook. Afmeting Laga Sten: 80 cm x 60 cm x 220 cm ( incl schoorsteen). Gewicht met steen (gletjer keien) 355 kg.De Laga Sten Tuin haard is voorzien van:- RVS schoorsteen- Gegalvaniseerde afneembare kap- Gegalvaniseerde metalen korf van 4 mm dik staaldraad- Gegalvaniseerd onderstel- Gegalvaniseerd  houtopslag ruimte- gegalvaniseerde aslade- Zwaar brand - kolen rooster- RVS BBQ rooster***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>HuisEnTuinWinkel</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>HuisEnTuinWinkel</b><br/>Voltastraat 92a<br/>7006 RW Doetinchem<br/>0314-362676<br/>";1.099,00;"Terrashaard Laga Sten Gletjer Keien";http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/media/catalog/product/f/i/file_2.JPG;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/skin/frontend/default/grayscale2014/images/logo.gif;;;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
169;;"Tuinhaard Laga StenLaga Sten een mooie tuin/terrashaard die met zijn tijd meegaat.Door de juiste keuze van stenen zal deze terrashaard altijd in uw tuin passen.Het grote voordeel is het rendement van deze kachel. De Laga Sten zorgt als vuurhaard voor een zeer gezellige en comfortabele warmte welke ook de stenen erom heen opwarmt. Deze stenen zorgen op hun beurt  voor een langdurig en behaaglijke warmte welke aanhoud tot lang nadat de Laga sten tuin haard gedooft is.***********************************************<br/>Vind ons in Google op: <b>HuisEnTuinWinkel</b><br/><br/>***********************************************<br/><b>HuisEnTuinWinkel</b><br/>Voltastraat 92a<br/>7006 RW Doetinchem<br/>0314-362676<br/>";1.199,00;"Terrashaard Laga Sten Beach Pebbles";http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/media/catalog/product/f/i/file_3.JPG;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/skin/frontend/default/grayscale2014/images/logo.gif;;;;;;;;Fixed;New;Send;True;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, but how about this:

```
sed 's|http://[^;]*/\([^;]*\)|\1|g'
```

Comment: what about `sed 's|http://[^;]*/||g` because file name is not modified nor after it ? Assuming there is no `http..../file.ext?option=12...;`

Comment: No, only the last url is changed and stored but I want to keep ALL the urls. So ;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/media/catalog/product/f/i/file_2.JPG;http://staging.huisentuinwinkel.nl/skin/frontend/default/grayscale2014/images/logo.gif; must become file_2.JPG;logo.gif;

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: I think you're right, but I want to make sure I've actually understood the SO before declaring the problem solved...

Comment: @Peter: I don't understand your comment. My sed command (and NeronLeVelu's simplified version) reduce that string to "file_2.JPG;logo.gif;". So... is this solution satisfactory?